# Pod situation after lack of resource on a node

Tags: kubernetes

I have two worker nodes on my cluster. On each one, there are five pods.

If one of my worker nodes fails, what would happen to five pods running on that node if we don't have enough resources for them on the healthy worker node?

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes has controllers that monitor the various resources that it manages (e.g., `Pod`s).  When a node goes down, Kubernetes will try to re-schedule the `Pod`s that were scheduled on that node to the remaining node(s).  If no remaining node has sufficient resources to schedule one or more of the `Pod`s, then those `Pod`s will remain in the `Pending` state.  Kubernetes will continue to *try* to find a place to run them, so if the failed node (or some other node) comes online, it will attempt to schedule the `Pending` pods on that node.

Answer (score -1):

That depends on what the software running there does in the face of lacking resources, and it course in the specific resource.

No general statement can be made.

Comment: my question is what is the status of pod in the explained situation? Is it in pending status until the resource supplies or anything else. I heard from someone that the pod is going to be in the pending status until the resource supplies and then it would create those pods.

Comment: Seems Emad is talking about Kubernetes given the use of the term "Pod".  Kubernetes' behavior is well-defined in this case.

Comment: That says positively nothing about the software running in these containers! Makes a difference what your database software does when it runs out of RAM, or when it runs out of disk space, or when it runs out of iops.... None here is well-defined, sorry. @AndyDalton I think you're making "resource" out to be a more specific term than it actually is!

Comment: @EmadKhavaninzadeh sorry, this is absolutely not sufficient to tell you anything. Pending - what? "Until the resource supplies": which resource, supplying what? Again, a pod just executes normal Linux software. What software does in reaction to missing resources is completely defined by the software. And you haven't told us anything about it, aside from it running in a pod.

Comment: @sinabala if the node goes down, no "normal Linux software" is running anymore -- the Pod is gone.  The question isn't about the software running in the containers, it is _What does Kubernetes do when a node goes down and no remaining node has the resources necessary to reschedule the pods?_, and that is well-defined.

Comment: Ah sorry! Yes, that makes sense..